# automatically running wine while double clicking .exe file on mac

Tags: macos, wine

I have already had wine on my mac, now I would like to know whether it's possible to automatically running wine when I double-click an .exe file (on Finder), because I believe wine doesn't go to my Application folder when I installed it...

If possible, how exactly?

PS: I don't know if this is needed, I use MacOS Lion.

Comment: Link to @zfm's SU post: http://superuser.com/questions/363303/automatically-running-wine-while-double-clicking-exe-file-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

We can use Apple Script to run the `exe` file.

1. Open Script Editor.
2. Add code below:

   ```
   tell application "Terminal"
   do script "'/Applications/Wine Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wine64'
   ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\\Files/$PATH_TO_PROGRAM.exe"
   end tell
   ```
3. Save as application (*not* as a script) on the Desktop
4. Double click to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question better asked on SuperUser.com, but anyways... if you click "Get Info" on your .exe app within the Finder, one of the items in the Info window that shows up will be "Open with:".

You can select WINE as the app to open those .exe files.

Comment: I don't have wine on the list of applications, can I just run X11 automatically?

Comment: Do you still have WINE installed?  If so, click on the "Other..." choice in that pop-up menu that appears under the "Open with" section and there is how you can select WINE.

Comment: There is no "WINE" there... I have done exactly what you told me to do... And to make sure that I have wine already, I typed wine on terminal and it worked...

Comment: where is WINE located on your machine?  type in "which wine" in Terminal and it will tell you.  You can then use that information to select for the "Open with" option in Finder.

Comment: that I have tried also, when I typed it, I got '/opt/local/bin/wine', but when I want to use it as my default application for .exe, I was not allowed to add that (probably because it's not recognized as an application)